# Create filter to handle exception JERSEY

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I need to create a filter that handles exception. In details when and exception occurres in my program with jersey filter I must return a 500 error.
This is my Filter.class:

```
@Provider
public class Filter implements ContainerResponseFilter {


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {


    }
}
```

How can I specify that when an exception is throwed this method is called and it return a 500 code error? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it extending *ExceptionMapper*:

```
@Provider
public class ApplicationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception ex) { 
       return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a filter I need a filter!